# Redirect 301 / Rewrite conundrum

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

On my site, users can add various URL's that need to be redirected.

For example; from this: domain.com/oldpage/36/

To this: domain.com/newpage/47/

They are added to the .htaccess like this:

```
Redirect 301 /oldpage/36/ /new-page/47/
```

But when accessing the old page they get this:

domain.com/newpage/47/?pid=36&pagename=oldpage

I'm pretty sure these rewrite rules are causing this predicament:

```
RewriteRule ([^.]+)/([0-9]+)/$ index.php?pid=$2&pagename=$1
RewriteRule ([^.]+)/([0-9]+)/([^.]+) index.php?pid=$2&pagename=$1&vars=$3
```

However, mod_rewrite stuff is not my strongpoint, so I have no idea how to fix it.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding a `?` makes the `Rewrite` not add the query string to the url.

so this should work:

```
Redirect 301 /oldpage/36/ /new-page/47/?
```

As a precaution you could also add it to the end of:

```
RewriteRule ([^.]+)/([0-9]+)/$ index.php?pid=$2&pagename=$1?
RewriteRule ([^.]+)/([0-9]+)/([^.]+) index.php?pid=$2&pagename=$1&vars=$3?
```

But only if they are needed

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply.That NEARLY works, the query string has been removed, but the question  mark remains, so I now have: domain.com/new-page/37/?

Comment: You might not be able to get rid of that. Is it such a big deal?

Comment: TBH, I think that's a small price to pay, so I think that'll do. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are already using mod_rewrite anyway, I suppose you should make your redirects using rewrites too

```
RewriteRule /oldpage/36/ /new-page/47/ [R=301]
```

This will "rewrite" the URL from old to new, and will redirect the browser to new url with status code `301`. `[R]` directive means redirect, which also stops other rules from processing, hence the other rules will be handled only when the new request is sent from broswer with new url.

Comment: you need `?` to the end of the url to remove the params which actually bothers him

Comment: There are no params at this point, I believe. Even if there is, it will redirect to the param-less url